# Firebase MLKit Text Recognition Error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I'm trying to OCR my image using Firebase MLKit but it fails and return with error

> Text detection failed with error: Failed to run text detector because self is nil.

```
/// Detects texts on the specified image and draws a frame for them.
func detectTexts() {
    let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "testocr")
    // Create a text detector.
    let textDetector = vision.textDetector()  // Check console for errors.

    // Initialize a VisionImage with a UIImage.
    let visionImage = VisionImage(image: image)
    textDetector.detect(in: visionImage) { (features, error) in
        guard error == nil, let features = features, !features.isEmpty else {
            let errorString = error?.localizedDescription ?? "No results returned."
            print("Text detection failed with error: \(errorString)")
            return
        }

        // Recognized and extracted text
        print("Detected text has: \(features.count) blocks")
        let resultText = features.map { feature in
            return "Text: \(feature.text)"
            }.joined(separator: "\n")
        print(resultText)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help me or let me know what's wrong before leaving a down vote.

Comment: I don't see where `vision` was declared, but I hope you did not forget to declare it: `lazy var vision = Vision.vision()`

Comment: Hello, did you resolve this? I am getting the identical error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you need to keep a strong reference to `textDetector`, otherwise the detector gets released before the completion block can be called.

Changing your code a bit:

```
var textDetector: VisionTextDetector?   // NEW

/// Detects texts on the specified image and draws a frame for them.
func detectTexts() {
    // ... truncated ...
    textDetector = vision.textDetector()   // NEW
    let visionImage = VisionImage(image: image)
    textDetector?.detect(in: visionImage) { (features, error) in   // NEW
        // Callback implementation
    }
}
```

You can also unwrap it to make sure it's not nil after you assign it:

```
guard let textDetector = textDetector else { 
    print("Error: textDetector is nil.")
    return
}
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

VisionTextDetector is no more supported so you have to use VisionTextRecognizer.
Here is an example code and I hope its helpful

```
   //MARK: Firebase var
 lazy var vision = Vision.vision()
   // replace VisionTextDetector with VisionTextRecognizer
     var textDetector:  VisionTextRecognizer? 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textDetector = vision.onDeviceTextRecognizer()
    }

// also instead of using detect use process now

     textDetector!.process(image) { result, error in

                guard error == nil, let result = result else {
                   //error stuff

                    return

                }
                let text = result.text
                self.textV.text = self.textV.text + " " + text
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf 
import cv2
import pytesseract as pt
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
model=tf.keras.models.load_model("license_plate_detector.h5")
#изображение
path = "datasets/mvd_1.jpg"
image = load_img(path)
image = np.array(image,dtype=np.uint8)
image1 = load_img(path,target_size=(224,224))
#обработка
image_arr_224 = img_to_array(image1)/225.0 
h,w,d = image.shape
test_arr = image_arr_224.reshape(1,224,224,3)
test_arr.shape
coords = model.predict(test_arr)
denorm = np.array([w,w,h,h,])
coords = coords * denorm
coords = coords.astype(np.uint32)
#РАмка 
xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax = coords[0]
pt1 = (xmin,ymin)
pt2 = (xmax,ymax)
print(pt1 , pt2)
cv2.rectangle(image,pt1,pt2,(0,255,0),2)
#преобразование в gray
test_license_plate = cv2.imread("datasets/mvd_1.jpg") 

resize_test_license_plate = cv2.resize( 
    test_license_plate, None, fx = 2, fy = 2,  
    interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

grayscale_resize_test_license_plate = cv2.cvtColor( 
    resize_test_license_plate, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gaussian_blur_license_plate = cv2.GaussianBlur( 
    grayscale_resize_test_license_plate, (5, 5), 0)
new_predicted_result = pt.image_to_string(gaussian_blur_license_plate, lang ='rus', config ='--oem 3 -l rus --psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=АВЕКМНОРСТУХ0123456789|') 

filter_new_predicted_result = "".join(new_predicted_result.split()).replace(":", "").replace("-", "") 

print(filter_new_predicted_result)
```

Comment: This is your fourth code-only answer. Please consider updating your questions with comments outlining how they solve the questions. Thanks.