# Firebase MLKit Text Recognition with Live Camera in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, text-recognition, firebase-mlkit

I am trying to build an iOS application that uses Firebase MLKit to recognize text from live camera frame.

I found an Android sample here.
https://medium.com/digital-curry/firebase-mlkit-textdetection-in-android-using-firebase-ml-vision-apis-with-live-camera-72ef47ad4ebd

Does anyone know good sample in iOS?

Comment: If you find my answer helpful then please don't forget to give me upvote.

Comment: Thank you for your help @MinuMaster. I 'd love to upvote you but I can't because my reputation is not enough for upvoting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Text Detection From Firebase MLKit:**

You can find demo code for Image to Text conversion using Firebase MLKit in iOS.

https://github.com/sayaleepote/TextDetect

For live recognization, you can create a custom camera and take a picture in the background periodically and detect a text from an image.

**Custom Camera View for Capture Images:**

For custom camera view, you can use below sample code.

Link: https://github.com/AlexLittlejohn/ALCameraViewController

**Note: You can achieve this feature using iOS native MLKit + Vision framework**

Refer This link for iOS native framework.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50918310

Let me know if you have any query.

Thanks.